# HTML and CSS help having 3 elements responsive like this

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want 3 elements in line. First two being aligned to the left and the third one being align to right. When the window is smaller I want the second going under the first while the third remains in the right, when the window gets even smaller all three under each other.

Here is an example:
https://www.backyardburgers.com/

I want to make the red thing under the header with those three elements an h2 a p and an anchor which is the button.

I would like if you could show me what CSS to use if the html is the following:

```
<section class="location"> 
<div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, copiosae perpetua voluptaria in pro, laboramus scriptorem instructior in usu, duo expetenda delicatissimi in. </p>
<a class="button" href="#">Sale sonet</a>
    </div></section>
```

Comment: Might want to look into using bootstrap as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example code with 3 divs](https://jsfiddle.net/8jtb0a8f/)

CSS ::::

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    div {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 500px) {
    div {
        display: block;
    }

   .first, .second {
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
   }

   .third{
        position: fixed;
        top: 8px;
        right: 5px;
        width: 200px;
   } 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
   div{
        display: inline-block;
   }

   .first {
        float: left;
   }

   .second {
        width: calc(100% - 410px);
   }

   .third {
        float: right;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 1):

> Here is a simple turnaround :

```css
.location {
  background: #d00807;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.location h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.location p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.location a.button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .location h2 {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .location p {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="location">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, copiosae perpetua voluptaria in pro, laboramus scriptorem instructior in usu, duo expetenda delicatissimi in. </p>
    <a class="button" href="#">Sale sonet</a>
  </div>
</section>
```